# Hudson keeps failing with Phing AND Ant. Any hints?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, hudson, phpunit, phing

Let's just skip right to the good stuff...

**errors I'm getting from the console when running Ant:**

```
phpunit:
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.2.16 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Class /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/AllTests could not be found in /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/AllTests.php.
     [exec] Result: 1

phpcpd:
     [exec] The referenced parameter '--log-pmd=/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/build/logs/pmd.xml' is not registered.
     [exec] Result: 1

pdepend:
     [exec] ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 4294967295 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/usr/bin/pdepend', line 57)
     [exec] PHP_Depend 0.9.16 by Manuel Pichler
     [exec] 
     [exec] Invalid directory '/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/build/logs/phpdepend.xml' added.
     [exec] Result: 2

phpcs:
     [exec] ERROR: The file "/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" does not exist.
```

**And when running Phing:**

```
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml of module logs with 1 warnings.
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in console log...
[TASKS] Scanning workspace files for tasks...
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
Publishing Javadoc
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Couldn't generate JDepend file at 'build/logs/phpdepend.xml'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/build/logs/phpdepend.xml (No such file or directory)
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/build/coverage called: clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/builds/2010-07-12_02-31-04/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
[xUnit] Starting to record.
[xUnit] Can't create the path /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/generatedJUnitFiles. Maybe the directory already exists.
[xUnit] [PHPUnit-5.1.6 (default)] - Processing 1 files with the pattern 'build/logs/*.xml' relative to '/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace'.
[xUnit] [WARNING] - The file '/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml' is an invalid file. It has been ignored.
[xUnit] The plugin hasn't been performed correctly: java.io.IOException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
GitAPI created
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/git tag -d hudson-Goals-31
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/git tag -a -f -m "Hudson Build #31" hudson-Goals-31-FAILURE
```

**So, any ideas what's going wrong? I get it to build just fine locally. On my VPS we get all this mess.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some path issues. You path `/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/build/logs/phpdepend.xml` seems to be a file, not a path.

> [exec] Invalid directory
>   '/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/build/logs/phpdepend.xml'
>   added.