# Hudson JDepend Plugin does not work

Tags: java, php, continuous-integration, hudson, jdepend

I am trying to build a continuous integration environment for php using hudson. 
I am running a shell script, which generates my phpdepend output, which can be used by the jdepend plugin.
Although the xml-File is ready, the plugin throws an exception:

console output:

```
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Couldn't generate JDepend file at 'jdepend.xml'java.lang.NullPointerException
```

on jdepend-symbol click:

```
 Report generation failed: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Failed to generate JDepend report:null
```

thanks for all your help.
Martin

Comment: Version of Maven?  Version of reporting plugin?  Maven command you are using?

Comment: JDepend Plugin 1.2.2, I am not using maven, I run a shell script generating the jdepend.xml.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same trouble. What was the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, it never worked for me. But strange, because there are not many posts about this topic. I wrote a small script to parse some values which were important for me and used the HTML Publisher plugin to display them.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that you have found a bug with this plugin (which seems like the case because you are getting a `NullPointerException`), go [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JDepend+Plugin) and look under the 'Bug reporting' section to see how to report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring a path, not a file.

See [Hudson keeps failing with Phing AND Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227343/hudson-keeps-failing-with-phing-and-ant-any-hints).

Comment: I do not unterstand. I tried pdepend-reports/ and pdepend-reports ... pdepend-reports contains my jdepend.xml. But I get the following error: [JDepend] Couldn't generate JDepend file at 'pdepend-reports'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/www/hosts/hudson-output/pdepend-reports (Is a directory)

Comment: Check permissions to the directory. Can the user Hudson runs under write to that location? look into that direction. look for typos in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but instead of putting the folder path, i put also the xml filename and it worked well, like this :

/build/logs/jdepend.xml